# Backup keystore.debug file

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-keystore

I recently uploaded my game on playstore made with unity but I forgot the password to the keystore when I tried to build an update.

After hours of googling I've learned the importance of the keystore file. After a few trial and error attempts I finally figured out the correct password.

However, what if in the future my keystore.debug file gets deleted accidentally? Will it be generated automatically again by unity or do I need to make a backup for this file on the cloud?

If I need to make a backup than do I need to backup only "user/.android/debug.keystore", or are there other files I need to backup as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some exaplanation:

`debug.keystore` (located on user/.android/debug.keystore) as the name implies, it is only used for debugging. That means, it's only used when you're sitting on your computer with the phone connected via ADB and typing code.

When developers release an app. Another keystore is used, the "release" keystore. That is the one you selected when clicking "Generate signed APK" or set on your gradle file, that you had to create a password for it. That file can be located anywhere on your system, you created it, you should know where it is. That one is very important. That one is the one that will allow you to update the app on the Play Store.

Direct answers:

- debug.keystore is disposable and you don't have to worry with it.
- the keystore used when exporting the .apk file, that one is VERY VERY important and YES, make backup of it everywhere you can! On an external hard-drive on your house, on a USB-drive and at least 1 cloud backup (e.g. Google Drive). If you loose that file or the password, you won't be able to update your app again.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to differentiate between `debug.keystore` & `release keystore`

- **`debug.keystore`** [Android User Guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

  > When running or debugging your project from the IDE, Android Studio automatically signs your APK with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords.

> No need to remember as its generated automatically

- **`release.keystore`**
  Needed to publish on google play console, But **take care** after you generate it and used to release signed version for push to production when you app become published you **can only** send updates using this key. it will be permanent for you app package name on Google play. You have to backup key and it's protection password too.